# Is there a theorem that states $\int f(x)g(x)dx = \int f(x)d g(x))$ or under certain conditions?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am working on a lecture on melcular dynamics

It starts with reminders , one of the reminders: average of a function with respect to density $\operatorname{Av}_{\rho}(g)=\int_{\mathcal{D}} g(x) \rho(x) \mathrm{d} x$ where $g$ is an observable function

Than in the slides that follwed gives examples, one of the examples :

$$
\int \varphi(q) \mathrm{d} \mu(q)
$$
Where:
$\varphi(q) \quad$ observable function
$\mathrm{d} \mu(q)$ Gibbs measure $\mathrm{d} \mu(q) \propto e^{-U} \mathrm{d} q$

It seems to me it replace a probability measure $(e^{-U} normalized)$ like $\frac{e^{-U}}{Z}dq$  with $\mu(q)$. But I don't know of a theorem or a result like this, (or I forgot)

I can think of product measure result but here it's is more like : $\int f(x)g(x)dx = \int f(x)d g(x)$

Is there a theorem that states such a result or these are separate?

Thank you so much

Comment: What does $d(g(x)\,dx)$ mean? Do you mean $dg(x)$?

Comment: Yes I made a mistake, I mean $dg(x)$, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x)g'(x)dx$ under appropriate conditions and $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x)g(x)dx$ can hold for all $f$ iff $g'(x)=g(x)$ or $g(x)=ce^{x}$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me please what theorem is this?

Comment: @squareroot you can find this under Riemann Steiltje's integrals in Apostol's book.

Comment: But here it is not the case since we have $e^{-U}$ instead of $ce^x$?

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong formula. If $g$ is continuously differentiable and $f$ is continuous then $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x)g'(x)dx$.